# Dart compiler or syntax check for command line

Tags: dart

Is there a way to call a Dart compiler just to verify the validity of my program without running it from the command line?

If I have a web_ui app I can call dwc, but what about a Dart library package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always run `dart_analyzer`, it's designed for this. It is actually (almost) the same code that powers the Dart Editor, so you can get syntax errors, static type warnings, deprecation warnings etc.

Comment: Good answer.  Here's [a link to a blog post which explains a bit more](http://japhr.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/regression-testing-of-dart-type-analysis.html), in which the author integrates dart_analyzer with drone.io continuous integration using command line scripts.